# Pytorch tensor put z values with x & y coordinates into grid

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm having a torch tensor of shape [3,N], where the three dimensions correspond to x,y,z values, respectively, and N is the number of data points. I.e., the tensor looks like this:

```
[x1, y1, z1]
[x2, y2, z2]
    ...
[xN, yN, zN]
```

The x&y values of the tensor correspond to x&y coordinates in an image, while the z value corresponds to the brightness at position [x,y]. Now what I want to do, is to reconstruct the image, based on the values of the tensor.

Normally, I do this with `torch.tensor.put_` ([Pytorch Reference](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.put_.html)).

The problem is, some x&y combinations appear multiple times in the image, i.e. I have multiple color values for a position [x,y], and I only want to keep the highest z-value at each position.

For example, lets take a 2x2 image. The tensor could then look like this:

```
[0,0,1]
[0,0,3]
[0,1,0]
[1,0,1]
[1,1,1]
[1,1,3]
[1,1,5]
```

And the desired output would then be

```
y
^
|  [0, 5]
|  [3, 1]
|
--------> x
```

Does anyone know how I could achieve this **without iterating over all datapoints N**, similar to the `torch.tensor.put_` method?